# codenameone POST request BODY

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, codenameone

I am using CodenameOne to send a POST request to a REST API.
It works perfectly with the GET because I do not have to pass a BODY with the message. 
Please can someone tell me how to pass a BODY with my post message?

Here is the code I am using to connect ...

```
    try {
        ConnectionRequest connReq = new ConnectionRequest();

        connReq.setPost(true);
        connReq.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "54321);
        connReq.addRequestHeader("client_id","12345");
        connReq.addRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        connReq.setUrl("https://myapi.com/connect");
        connReq.setHttpMethod("POST");
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(connReq);
        Map<String,Object> result = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(connReq.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));
        return result; 
    }
    catch(Exception err) {
        System.err.println(err);
        return null;
    }
```

I have found some documentation here - but I can't quite understand what they are telling me ...

https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.html#buildRequestBody-java.io.OutputStream-

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want a standard "FORM" style post which is what you would get if you have fields in an HTML form just use `addArgument` as you would with `GET`. It will work with `POST` just fine.

If you want to "hardcode" your body e.g. some webservices expect JSON to be the body of the request just write it into the output stream in the `buildRequestBody` method you found.

Comment: I am trying this .... ByteArrayOutputStream bOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); bOutput.write("\"Key\": \"Value\"".getBytes()); try { ..... connReq.buildRequestBody(bOutput); ..... } But I get this error ... buildRequestBody(OutputStream) has protected access in ConnectionRequest What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `buildRequestBody` method is a callback that you should override by subclassing the `ConnectionRequest`.

Comment: Thanks - I have done this and now at least it is building. However the body is still blank. When I debug and step through I can see that the data being passed into my new overriden buildRequestBody method is valid. I have noticed in the watch window that the 'data' byte[] variable is null. Should this be populated?

Comment: I'm guessing you fell into one of the inner class variable scoping pitfalls of Java I'll need to see the code and the specific line to help you with that. I suggest filing a new question with revised code or editing this question with the up to date code. If you choose the latter option don't forget to comment here as I won't get a notification on a question edit

Comment: I have posted a new question. Thanks